# Software that listens to defined port and fires a defined action

Tags: stream, router, telnet, fritzbox

I want to setup a call monitor for showing incoming calls. My router (fritzbox) has a function, that sends for every event (incoming-, outgoing call...) a telnet stream. I can only see it via putty. I'm a webcoder, and have no idea how to grab this stream.

My question: Is there a software, which can fire an action( f.e call a url), when a defined telnet stream gets a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by webcoder but if you are comfortable with building a PHP web server, for example, you should be able to do this.

In very high level terms you could:

- create a web server and have a page which displays a list of call events, reading the list from a local database on the server. The web page would refresh the call list, using an AJAX request  if you are comfortable or familiar with this, every second. If you are not familiar with AJAX just refresh the entire page every second.
- create a simple php script on the same web server which runs in the background and which reads from the Fritzbox telnet connection every couple of seconds and adds any new call events into the database.

This will keep your call logs up to date, albeit with an amount of polling overhead.

Comment: the problem is, that the php script must run forever, beacause my router is not providing a list. I get only live-infos. And i thoght, that PHP is not the right language for this.

Comment: You can set a script or service or daemon to run continuously so it is running all the time your web server is running. The language does not really matter the same approach will work with different languages. Whether PHP is a suitable language is probably into the realm of religious debate but you can certainly implement this using PHP. I would use whatever language you are most familiar with.